# Rails 4 - Prevent access to previously created routes from subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Currently, I have a user model and an admin model (both utilizing Devise). I've made a subdomain called admin and I want it to be independent from the main domain.

How can I prevent current paths from being accessed through the subdomain?

For example, www.example.com/sign_up redirects a user to the USER sign up page. However, admin.example.com/sign_up also redirects me to the same user sign up page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE

What I ended up doing was creating a method in my controllers that I didn't want to have access to my subdomain. Had this run before every action.

```
def subdomain_teacher?
    if request.subdomain == 'teacher'
      raise ActionController::RoutingError.new('Not Found')
    end
end
```

Not a great solution, but it works for the time being. If anyone has a better way of doing it, please let me know